# Copy Variable's Contents to Clipboard VBA (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, vba

I know this should be a super easy solution but I can't fathom it out.

I'm just making a simple button which copies the values in the range of 'Output' to my clipboard.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Output As String
    Output = Range("Output")
    MsgBox (Output + " Text has been copied")
End Sub
```

I want Output to copy to my clipboard.

Edit:

Many Thanks
Sam

Comment: Hello, You can remove the Edits and answer your own question and then mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a 180 on it and changed it around,

Solution below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myData As DataObject
Dim Output As String

Output = UCase(InputBox("Type Text Here"))

If Output = "" Then
End
Else
End If
Set myData = New DataObject
myData.SetText Output
myData.PutInClipboard
MsgBox (Output + " text has been copied")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better declaring Output as an object variable (or, more specifically, as a range).

You can then use the value of the range within the messagebox, whilst also copying the value to the clipboard.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Output As Range
    Set Output = Range("Output")

    Output.Copy
    MsgBox (Output + " Text has been copied")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I did a U turn and it worked out much better:

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myData As DataObject
Dim Output As String

Output = UCase(InputBox("Type Text Here"))

If Output = "" Then
End
Else
End If
Set myData = New DataObject
myData.SetText Output
myData.PutInClipboard
MsgBox (Output + " text has been copied")
End Sub
`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the `Values` of a `Range` which is called "Output"

The script below will add join (like the WorkSheetFunction "Concantenate") and then display it in the `MsgBox` and copy it to the ClipBoard.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Output As Range
    Dim MyString As String
    Dim OutputText As DataObject

    Set OutputText = New DataObject
    Set Output = Range("A1:A5")

    MyString = ""

    For Each cell In Output

        MyString = MyString & cell.Value & " "

    Next cell

    OutputText.SetText MyString
    OutputText.PutInClipboard

    MsgBox (MyString + " Text has been copied")

End Sub
```